# Using factory method to incorporate different classes (c++)

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I give the following codes to illustrate my question:

```
class Basic 
{
  public:
      Basic();
      ~Basic();
};

class ExtendA: public Basic
{
  public:
      class Para
      {
       };
      Para para_;

};
class ExtendB: public Basic
{
   public:
    class Para
    {

     };
    Para para_;
};

enum Method
{
   MedExtendA, 
   MedExtendB,
   MedExtendAVar1,
   MedExtendBVar1
};

class Enginee
{
 public: 
     class Para()
     {
      public:
         ExtendA::Para paraA_;
         ExtendB::Para paraB_;
     };
     Para paraEnginee_;
     Enginee(Method med)
     {
         switch(med):
         {
           case MedExtendA:
              pBasic.reset(new ExtendA());
              break;
           case MedExtendAVar1:
              pBasic.reset(new ExtendA());
              ExtendA *p = dynamic_cast<ExtendA *> (pBasic.get());
              p.para_ = ; // set the parameter
              break;
           case MedExtendB:
                 ...
              break;
           case MedExtendBVar1:
                  ...
              break;

         }
     }
     ~Enginee()
     {
      }
     boost::shared_ptr<Basic> pBasic;
 };
```

From the above example, we can see that `Basic` is the base class while `ExtendA` and `ExtendB` are derived class based on `Basic` class. class `Enginee` is a factory class, which facilitates invoking other classes. The reason why `Enginee` class is needed can be shown in the following example:

Without `Enginee` class:

```
ExtendA objA;
objA.para_ /// parameter setting
objA.do_something();
```

With Enginee class:

```
   Enginee myEngine(MedExtendAVar1);
     myEngine.do_something();
```

In a word, using factory method to construct a `Enginee` class gives a uniform interface for using `ExtendA` and `ExtendB` class. In the above example, depending on parameter setting, we can kind of create different varieties of classes, which can be invoked very easily. However, it also makes the codes more complicated. So here is my question: are there other alternative solutions? what's the problem of the proposed solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "incorporating different classes?" What's the problem you want to solve? Do you need to instantiate classes of varying types that are only determined at runtime? Or are you simply encapsulating basic polymorphism?

Comment: @TimStraubinger Thanks. I have reedited the name of the title. The main question is what kind of problem of using the factory design pattern method to incorporatrice different classes as shown in the example.

Comment: I believe [Abstract Factory](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) is more suit to your problem thant Factory Method.

Answer (score 3):

> Is factory method the only way of incorporating different classes?

No.

I'm not quite sure I understand your question correctly. But if I do and you are asking if a factory class is the only way to instantiate your derived classes and get a base-class pointer to them, then the answer is "no".

You could simply do `Base* b = new ExtendA;`.

If I misunderstood your question, then just disregard my answer but please attempt to clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks, and I have named the title of my question. Thanks.